# Integrating the product of the Heaviside function with 1/x

Tags: integration

I have a problem with the integration in the following.

Given a function $f(x,y)$ and a region $R$ in the $x-y$ plane,
\begin{equation}
F(y)=\int_{l_0}^{L_0}\frac{1}{x}f(x,y)dx,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = [1-\mathscr{H}(y-bx)] \left ( \frac{1}{bx} - \frac{1}{x} \right )
+ [\mathscr{H}(y-bx)-\mathscr{H}(y-L_0)] \left ( \frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{x} \right ),
\end{equation}
and 
$\mathscr{H}$ is the Heaviside function and $l_0 \ll y < L_0$.

The answer is
\begin{equation}
F(y) = \frac{-\ln{b}}{y} - \frac{1}{bL_0}.
\end{equation}

I'm not sure whether to approach this.
Any helps to get me started would be greatly appreciated.